# Have Java's Mongo Driver throw an exception if it can't connect to server

Tags: java, mongodb, database-connection

Is there a way of having Java's Mongo client (version 2.13.2) throw an exception if it couldn't connect to the server?

I have a line in my code like the one shown below:

`mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));`

and I like it to throw an exception if the server is down and the connection failed.

I've seen other answers in Stack Overflow and the Mongo mailing list, but all of them seem to go through attempting to fetch a database using the MongoClient and see if it throws and `Exception`. I would very much would like to avoid that if possible. I don't want to get a database: I want to test connectivity (they're different things, and testing by trying to get a database seems... dirty)

If I try to set a read preference (`mongoClient.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());`) I do see an exception in the console:

```
INFO  [2016-01-29 16:56:43,847] org.mongodb.driver.cluster: Exception in
 monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

but that is not even bubbled up.. it seems to be failing in another process or thread or being caught?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look at this [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616695/connection-to-non-existing-mongodb-server-does-not-throw-exception)